# How to bind same Table's data on multiple tab on Tabcontrol using Datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Based on my requirement i can't bind same table's data on multiple tabitems but able to do different table data on multiple Tabitems on Tabcontrol

example: i want table1 data on tab1 and tab2 using datagrid, which is not possible
but if i want table1 data on tab1 and table2 data on tab2 using same datagrid it is possible..

So My Question is how to bind same table's data on multiple tab using datagrid

using VS2010

Comment: Can you please provide a bit of more information like screen shots or anything that you might have tried..

Comment: as far as my knowledge is concerned, if it is problem related to datatable only then you can create dataTable2 value with datatable1.copy()

Comment: @D_Learning when i bind same table in tab1 and tab2 
o/p is http://www.imagesup.net/?di=614226784684 & http://www.imagesup.net/?di=114226782477    but when i bind different table data i am getting http://www.imagesup.net/?di=614226784684 & http://www.imagesup.net/?di=7142267984814.. ..

Comment: @kumartyr: If you are still having the issue then can please reply else disregard the below. Are you binding a list or a DataTable ? Also if you can just copy both the grid's XAML code as well as code behind of binding then it would be really helpful to finding the problem as well as solution.

Comment: @D_Learning  I did the same after posting my image URL to u & it worked.. but still i dont know why it didn't worked previously..Any way got the solution..thanks for your help & time.